# How to format data in tree structure

Tags: java, sorting, tree

I am collecting some hierarchical data from DB. I already have the data, but I am trying to figure how to format it in tree structure. What I have for data:

```
private void getChildren(String parent) throws SQLException {
    Stack childrenFromDb = getChildrenFromDb(parent);
    while (!childrenFromDb.empty()){
        String pop = String.valueOf(childrenFromDb.pop());
        if (processedKeys.get(pop) != null) continue;
        stringBuilder.append(String.format(String.format("%s\t\t%%s\n", parent), pop));
        processedKeys.put(pop, pop);
        getChildren(pop);
    }
}
```

So at the moment it is formatting it in a table like

> ID\t\tParentId

I want to get something like [this.](http://www.systemcentercentral.com/Portals/0/VivoIndexItem/Index55740/WLW-ListManagementPacksDependenciesPowersHel_EA2B-image_thumb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to format it is to add a depth parameter to your getChildren() function. Something like:

```
getChildren(String parent, int depth);
```

That way you could use a for loop to add spacing based on the depth.

On a side note, getChildren() implies that a child object will be returned, it might be beneficial to rename the function to something like printChildren() as that is more what it's doing.

Comment: Personally, instead of a numeric depth param, I'd simply give a "prefix" String. So in every step of the recursion you just add prefix+"  |" or something like that.

Comment: I does work, thaks man. I added depth to parameters and when recuresevly calling I just do `getChildren(pop, depth + 1);` and when printing I add depth times tabs.